# How to extend (add new prototype property) existing (already declared) classes in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I want to add new method `catchAndLog` to existing `Promise` class.

In plain JS, it's easy as `Object.defineProperty(Promise.prototype, 'catchAndLog', ...)`. However, it seems typescript does not understand this.

How do I let typescript compiler know that `Promise` now has an additional member property so that it doesn't complain when I do `Promise.reject('error').catchAndLog()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in the same way as in Javascript, the only catch is you need to add a definition for the newly added methods so that typescript knows about it.

```
declare global { // Remove this enclosing global if you are not in a module
    interface Promise<T> {
        catchAndLog(): Promise<T>
    }
}

Object.defineProperty(Promise.prototype, 'catchAndLog', {

})

Promise.reject('error').catchAndLog()
```